# Adding a prefix "#" to certain string values in an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What I'm trying to do is add a check to my for loop that searches for "value_1" or "value_3". If found, than add a "#" at the beginning of that value.

Ex: #value_1, value_2, #value_3, etc

Here's my code:

```
for(i=1; i < columns.length-1; i++){
    currentRecordKey = columns[i].dataIndex;
    if(currentRecordKey == "value_1" || "value_3") {
        currentRecordKey = "#" + currentRecordKey;
    }
}
```

Worked out in my head, but this doesn't get the job done.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What seems to be the issue? You haven't explained where your code goes wrong or what you're trying to fix.

Comment: `"value_3"` is alway truthy. Looks like you have a typo.

Comment: Sorry My post was riddled with typos haha. But the -1 is necessary for the grid that I have set up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
for(i=1; i < columns.length-1; i++){
    //icon record
    var currentRecordKey = columns[i].dataIndex;
    if(currentRecordKey == "value_1" || currentRecordKey == "value_3") {
         currentRecordKey = "+" + currentRecordKey ;
    }
    columns[i].dataIndex = currentRecordKey;
}
```

Your error is that if you don't restate that you are checking for `currentRecordKey == "value_3"`, JavaScript will only check if `currentRecordKey` is true, and any non-empty string is.

Also, I've commented out `icon record` which might also be a typo.

*Edit:* also fixed the issue explained by Jasper and made `currentRecordKey` a local variable.

Comment: If you want to alter the data in the `columns` array then this won't do it, it's still saving the "updated" string in a separate variable which will be overwritten each iteration of the loop. But if you're looking to do work with that new variable within the loop, you should be good to go.

Comment: @Jasper: fixed the issue

Comment: Oh, no fix really needed I think. The OP hasn't stated what they're really after, nice answer though.